# grunt htmlcompressor failed Error not found java

Tags: java, visual-studio, gruntjs

in visual studio 2015 when running grunt task htmlcompressor, 
the task returns 
`>> Error: Error: not found: java
Warning: htmlcompressor failed to compress html. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
Process terminated with code 6.`

the task code:

```
htmlcompressor: {
        compile: {

            files: [{
                expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
                cwd: 'Scripts/Ng-Views/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
                src: ['**/*.html'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
                dest: 'wwwroot/Views/',   // Destination path prefix.
            }],

            options: {
                type: 'html',
                preserveServerScript: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be encountering an old issue with [grunt-htmlcompressor](https://github.com/jney/grunt-htmlcompressor).

In the GitHub repo for the plugin there is a *closed* issue that includes a workaround for updating `PATH` environment to `java.exe`. See the last post [here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.co.uk&sl=fr&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://github.com/jney/grunt-htmlcompressor/issues/4&usg=ALkJrhj11obns2V78Y9DL8yBgz07WALOCA) for further info. It reads:

> For Windows another workaround will be update "PATH" environment variable buy adding the path to "java.exe", for example: 
>   Start> Right click on "Computer"> Properties> Advanced system configuration> Advanced options (tab)> Enviroment vars> Edit PATH and add path to java.exe C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Java \ jre7 \ bin)
>   NOTE: If you have cmd open, close it and open it again, otherwise will not work.